# C2001: Closure Compiler Error (Parse error. invalid assignment target) -- compression-input:210:74

Tags: extjs

when running Sencha Cmd v7.0.0.40, i get the following error message:

```
[ERR] C2001: Closure Compiler Error (Parse error. invalid assignment target) -- compression-input:210:74
```

I can't find the error caused by that code. Is there any way to quickly locate the error in the JS file?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the java VM running out of heap space when trying to compress.
There may be a better way to up the heap space, but I do it with an environment variable.

I put this in my .profile.

_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx2g

This will up the heap for all java executions.
Notice the "_" (underscore).